# Fragmenting XSL stylesheets

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo, apache-cocoon

The stylesheet I'm using currently to transform XML to PDF has become really big and going out of control. It has become a maintenance nightmare.

I'm planning to redesign this style sheet by splitting it into various stylesheets depending on its functionality. There should be one main xsl, and 3-4 secondary xsls. Based on some of the conditions in main xsl, it should jump to the appropriate secondary xsl. It is possible to do that?

Update: I'm using version 1.0

Edit: I'm using apache cocoon for generating pdf from XML. Was wondering if there is a way to pre-process the incoming XML and decide which XSL should handle this(Based on parameters in XML)?

Comment: Have you looked into the use of the `<xsl:import>` element?  I don't think there's a way to specifically direct processing to a specific imported XSLT, but you could use modes and named templates to control what gets used where.

Answer (score 2):

You may find that rather than having "main xsl ... jump to the appropriate secondary xsl", it's better to have several task-oriented entry points, each represented by one stylesheet module, and then have a common module containing stuff that's shared between the different entry points. This makes it much easier to take advantage of xsl:import: each task-oriented stylesheet imports the common stylesheet and overrides anything in the common stylesheet that isn't appropriate to the particular task.

Comment: I'm quite new to xsl and fop. We are using cocoon to convert the xml to PDF. Can I tweek the sitemap.xmap to set the task based entry points?
Decision making is based on certain parameters inside the input xml file.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 certainly allows you to write stylesheet modules and to incorporate them into a main stylesheet, with the help of `xsl:import` or `xsl:include` (http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Combining-Stylesheets).

However your use of the term "jump to the appropriate secondary xsl" sounds rather procedural. To me XSLT is mainly about writing templates that match nodes in the input and to push nodes to these matching templates using `xsl:apply-templates`. Whether those template are in a separate file or not does not matter in most cases, with the exception of import precedence and `xsl:apply-imports`, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#apply-imports.